# Foundation column layout not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I have a bit of code:

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <div class="row">
<% @just_products.each do |i| %>
  <% just_names = i['Name'] %>
  <% just_prices = i['UnitPrice'] %>
  <% just_descriptions = i['Description'] %>
    <div class="large-3 columns panel radius"><h2><%=h just_names %></h2><br><h3><%=h just_prices %></h3><br>
    <p><%=h just_descriptions %></p></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The output isn't what I thought it would be. I'm going for 4 product blocks in each row and as you can see below some of them are very misaligned.
[image: Foundation error]

Trying to figure out why it goes 4 x 4 x 2 x 4 x 1 x 4 x 4 x 2 instead of 4 x 4 x 4 x 4 x 4 x 4 x 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a **fixed height** for your product columns otherwise the floated element will catch on another taller element or clear it all together. You may want to checkout either **http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout** or **[masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/.)**

Please let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The grid will always be this way if you are working with variable height columns, if you want that columns just snap under each other then you should use a jQuery plugin called isotope